# Command line to backup schedulded tasks in Windows 7

Tags: windows, backup, windows-7

How can I create a backup of my schedulded tasks so that I can restore them on my backup server easily?

**Edit:** I would prefer a command line version, so that the backup of the schedulded tasks is a job on its own so that I do not miss any changes.

Comment: I made the edit more apparent so people wouldn't overlook that you would prefer a command line way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a command line solution, try one of the following two:

- Copy all files in the "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks" folder ala RoboCopy
- Play around with the command `schtasks /query /xml ONE` and pipe the output into a .xml file. So... `schtasks /query /xml ONE >> myTasks.xml`

More on schtasks can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) and [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Right click on each one, and choose export, they appear to be in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

following steps:

1.Open Scheduled Tasks on your local machine (go to Start, Settings, Control Panel, Scheduled Tasks).

2.Right-click the task your want to move or copy.

Click here to view image

3.If you want to copy the task, select Copy, and if you want to move the task, select Cut.

4.Open My Network Places in Windows Explorer, expand the domain or workgroup, and select the target machine where you want to copy or move the task.

5.Right-click the target machine's Scheduled Tasks, and click Paste.